# How to use current version of opengl in cygwin?

Tags: opengl, cygwin

I have been using OpenGL with cygwin for a few months to program some 3d applications.  I now want to attempt to write some slightly more advanced techniques using things like vertex buffer objects.  However, I noticed that I ran into an obstacle:  when I use `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` in my program it spits out 1.4.

I compile my program with these flags: `-lGL -lglut -lGLU -lGLEW` and have included these headers: `freeglut.h glew.h`.  I have chosen to link against the X11 libraries vs. the windows ones as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389488/compiling-minimal-glew-application-under-cygwin).  My current OpenGL programs build and are able to run (because up until now, I have used older functionality--pre-OpenGL 1.4).

I have a new desktop computer with an ATI FirePro V4800 (FireGL) graphics card that can support up to OpenGL 4.1.  I have installed the latest drivers and it passes the tests supplied by the program: OpenGL Extensions Viewer. In addition, the program shows that all the extensions up to and including 4.1 are available for my graphics card.

There is a brief mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344/starting-off-with-opengl-under-cygwin) under the last answer saying that cygwin may want to use older dlls (ones that don't support shaders, etc.).  Is this a cygwin problem?  Will cygwin just not recognize my latest drivers and offer me the cool stuff in OpenGL 4.1?  Or am I not linking to the correct libraries?

**UPDATE**

After getting to know how Cygwin's X Server works I figured I should switch to freeglut's native windows libraries.  I grabbed the pre-compiled binaries found [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) and put the files in appropriate directories to link against them.  After recompiling I am able to use all the options found in OpenGL as my graphics card permits (4.1).

Comment: What makes you think that this has anything to do with Cygwin (which is nothing more than a shell)? It's more likely to be your code than Cygwin.

Comment: OK. Perhaps I don't understand how cygwin interacts with my system's drivers.  I have tried an example program found on this [site](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1:_Rendering_shapes_with_glDrawRangeElements,_VAO,_VBO,_shaders_%28C%2B%2B_/_freeGLUT%29) and receive an error saying `glXCreateContextAttribsARB not found`

Comment: @NicolBolas: He's using OpenGL through the Cygwin X server. That server's GLX implementation only supports OpenGL-1.4

Comment: ah, thank you...that is the information I was looking for.

Comment: @chembrad How about you answer your own question? You know so it is marked as answered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Cygwin's X-server, start it with -wgl option (current versions do that automatically) then

```
export LIBGL_USE_WGL=1
```

On the machine I'm posting from, I get:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500
OpenGL version string: 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.3062
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.00 - Build 9.17.10.3062
[...]
```

Unsetting the environment variable:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
[...]
```

Comment: I followed these instructions (X -wgl, export LIBGL_USE_WGL=1), but glxinfo still reports VMWare / Gallium as the backend.

Comment: After RTFM (http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-aiglx.html) I got it to work by running X -wgl -multiwindow . For reasons I don't know, the indirect rendering (+iglx) does not work here.